# Create Custom Background For TextView Android

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I want to develop a text view background as shown below image:

[image]

How should I achieve this? and the yellow dot will change based on data.

Comment: overlay the yellow circle with white border on top of 13

Comment: ok. I will try this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have just spend sometime to achieve same. This is not perfect, but you can refer this at-least . :)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/d10dp"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/d10dp"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/d10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/d10dp">
    <item 
        android:id="@+id/item1">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#3CF8C2"/>
            <corners android:radius="12dp"/>
            <size
                android:width="40dp"
                android:height="40dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item 
        android:id="@+id/item2"
        android:width="16dp"
        android:height="16dp"
        android:end="-2dp"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:top="-2dp">
        <shape
            android:gravity="right"
            android:shape="oval">
            <stroke
                android:width="2dp"
                android:color="#fff"/>
            <solid android:color="#FFC730"/>
            <size
                android:width="16dp"
                android:height="16dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

To dynamically change color of drawable, refer below code.

Find drawable by id and change its color:

```
 LayerDrawable shape = (LayerDrawable) ContextCompat.getDrawable(YourActivity.this,R.drawable.here_drawable_name)
 GradientDrawable gradientDrawable = (GradientDrawable) shape.findDrawableByLayerId(R.id.item2);
 gradientDrawable.setColor(Color.Green); // changing color to Green
```

Comment: it should work, but I want to change the yellow dot based on data. Could you please help me how should I change it runtime

Comment: Cannot resolve symbol 'item2' could you please help

Comment: yes, I have already updated the drawable file still facing the same issue. My min SDK version is 19 does it cause any issue?

Comment: it's in drawable folder

Comment: it's working. please change your answer coz you accidentally add shape instead of layerDrawable. Thanks a lot. I marked as an accepted answer

Comment: I also need to make same background in one of my project. Thanks man for spending some time.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to do like this before. Maybe it helps.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="16dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:background="@color/blue"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="13" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```